# Write automatically in services.yml file

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I want to create a php class that writes automatically a service in the services.yml file based on my entities ( on server run or with a command ) .Is it possible to do so or should I just use the filesystem to do it ?

Comment: As @chalasr has shown you certainly can.  But if you have not already then take a look at Symfonys configuration http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/index.html and compiler passes http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html.  They may suit your needs better.  Quite a few of the Symfony services are actually dynamically generated or modified.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but the newly created service will be unavailable until the next request.

To retrieve the `services.yml` of a bundle :

```
// src/AcmeBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$servicesPath = $kernel->locateResource('@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml');`
```

Or the global `services.yml` of your application :

```
$servicesPath = $kernel->getRootDir().'/config/services.yml';``
```

Write your new service into :

```
$parser = new \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser();
$dumper = nrw \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper();

// Get the services already configured, use the path of 'services.yml' retrieved from bundle/application
$oldServices = $parser->parse($servicesPath); 
$newService = array('your_service_name' => array( 
   // Here your arguments, tags, ...
);

$mergedServices = array_merge($oldServices, $newService);
$yamlServices = $dumper->dump($mergedServices);

// Write all in the configuration file
file_put_contents($servicesPath, $yamlServices); // $services is the 'services.yml' path
```

Comment: Can I do the same thing with config.yml and security.yml or this  solution is only for services (i'm trying to automate the generation of a secure api )

Comment: Of course, you can. You have to find the good way to manually write an entry for each of this configuration files. For that, just look at the retrieved YAML in `$oldServices` and see the correct format for build your array and merge it into `$oldServices`.

Comment: I have correctly configured the api and secured it with jwt ; Now I just have to automate the file writing ...thank you !